# plot histogram with freq=FALSE displaying integer values on y-axis

Tags: r

I have a vector of several million observations that I would like to display as a histogram with relative frequencies.

I executed the following:

```
h = hist(temp_tally)
h$counts = h$counts / sum(h$counts)
plot(h, freq = FALSE)
```

The resulting histogram has a Y-axis labeled with integer values from 0-5, which clearly are not frequencies. I tried a simple toy example using

```
temp_tally = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,7,8,10,10)
```

and the same procedure generated a histogram with a y-axis labeled with densities between 0 and 1 as it should be. What could be going on that would generate such a strange "densities" as the ones I'm seeing with my actual data?

Comment: The `plot` method for `"histogram"`-class objects assumes that the `h$counts` is integers, you are defeating that with your `counts/sum(counts)` logic.

Comment: Since the code works with the `temp_tally` provided above and allegedly not with your "real" `temp_tally`, it's difficult to really investigate the issue without a more representative "does not work" dataset. Can you share enough of your real data that performs incorrectly?

Comment: I'll see if I can come up with a toy example with the same issue. The problem with the dataset is that it's a vector of length 8e+6. Taking small subsets of it does not replicate the problem

Comment: I think I have circumvented the problem by setting h$density = h$counts/sum(h$counts). When I do this, plot(h, freq=FALSE) returns a histogram of relative frequencies.